# How should I join the following sentence so it becomes an adjective?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

> Wow, that was the most philosophical
>   **I-don't-care-that-you're-not-a-virgin** explanation I've ever heard.

Should I write it like this? Or should I omit some words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `that` is redundant. You could do away with it. Otherwise it's fine.

> Wow, that was the most philosophical I-don't-care-you're-not-a-virgin
>   explanation I've ever heard.